# what is the most easy to read Algebraic Geometry book?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

All:

what is the most easy to read (most accessible) Algebraic Geometry book ?

(If possible, I am looking for an introduction book, maybe for undergraduate, and maybe similar to A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory).

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's the "Introduction to Algebraic Curves" of William Fulton. He let you download the book from his site. Here is the link:

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I am fans of both

Hartshorne - Algebraic Geometry  which is quite a classical text

For a more friendly introduction try

Eisenbug & Harris - The Geometry of Schemes.

Comment: Hartshorne is the best reference but it isn't the easier book about the subject.

Comment: Not only is Hartshorne not "the easier book about the subject": it is a horrendous book to try to begin with into algebraic geometry. Also the Eisenbud-Harris book: is way into graduate level, and it definetely cannot be regarded as an "introduction".